# Как проверить есть ли в строке числа

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим у меня есть переменная
var text = "ab2c";
И мне нужно проверить есть ли в этой переменной числа (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)

Comment: И вообще никаких идей?

Comment: Числа или цифры? - это разные вещи. Возможно вы, не правильно задаете вопрос. К числу к примеру относится "21" - это как цельное число, а к цифрам к примеру 2 и 1, это уже две разные цифры. Вопрос, про что? Вобще не понятно.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант - использовать [регулярные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions), для поиска цифр или чисел в строке:

```
let str = 'asd123asd12ds2'
str.match(/\d/g);    // вернёт массив с цифрами
                     // ['1','2','3','1','2','2']

str.match(/(\d+)/g); // вернёт массив с числами
                     // ['123','12','2']
```

Ниже представлен пример:

```js
let str = 'asd123asd12ds2';

let number = str.match(/\d/g);    // массив с цифрами
let numbers = str.match(/(\d+)/g);// массив с числами

$('#str').html(str);

$('#d_pre').html(`[<br>  <span class="rc">"${number.join('"</span>,<br>  <span class="rc">"')}"</span><br>]`);
$('#dp_pre').html(`[<br>  <span class="rc">"${numbers.join('"</span>,<br>  <span class="rc">"')}"</span><br>]`);

$('#d_view').html(str.replace(/(\d)/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
$('#dp_view').html(str.replace(/(\d+)/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
```

```css
.code,
.code_block {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #222;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.code {
  display: inline-block;
}

.code_block {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  white-space: pre;
}

.rc {
  color: #bd0000;
}

#d_view,
#dp_view {
  font-size: 130%;
  letter-spacing: .25rem;
}

#d_view  > span:nth-child(1),
#dp_view > span:nth-child(1) {background: red;}
#d_view  > span:nth-child(2),
#dp_view > span:nth-child(2) {background: orange;}
#d_view  > span:nth-child(3),
#dp_view > span:nth-child(3) {background: yellow;}
#d_view  > span:nth-child(4),
#dp_view > span:nth-child(4) {background: green; color: #fff;}
#d_view  > span:nth-child(5),
#dp_view > span:nth-child(5) {background: aqua;}
#d_view  > span:nth-child(6),
#dp_view > span:nth-child(6) {background: blue; color: #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Есть строка: <span id="str" class="code"></span><br>
<br>
<span class="code">.match(<span class="rc">/\d/g</span>)</span> - найдёт в ней все цифры и вернёт массив.<br>
Если это визуализировать, то получится следующее:<br>
<span class="code" id="d_view"></span>
<br>
Тут видно, что каждая найденая цифра - это отдельный элемент массива:
<div class="code_block" id="d_pre"></div>
<br><br>
А <span class="code">.match(<span class="rc">/(\d+)/g</span>)</span> - найдёт именно числа и тоже вернёт массив.<br>
Этот момент тоже визуализируем:<br>
<span class="code" id="dp_view"></span>
<br>
В этом случае, регулярное выражение будет "проверять" следующий символ и если оно будет числом, то соберётся некая группа из которых будет массив:
<div class="code_block" id="dp_pre"></div>
```